# Transitive dependency errors in SBT multi-project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am building a SBT multi-project project, which has `common` module and `logic` module, and `logic.dependsOn(common)`.

In `common`, SparkSQL 2.2.1 ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1") is introduced. In `logic`, SparkSQL also is used, however I get compilation errors, saying "object spark is not a member of package org.apache".

Now, if I add SparkSQL dependency to `logic` as `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"`, it works. However if I add `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1" % Provided"`, I get the same error.

I don't get why this happened, why not the dependency can't be transitive from `common` to `logic`

here is the root sbt files:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "...",
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
  resolvers ++= Seq(
    clojars,
    maven_local,
    novus,
    twitter,
    spark_packages,
    artima
  ),
  test in assembly := {},

  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {...}
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(common, logic)

lazy val common = (project in file("common")).settings(commonSettings:_*)

lazy val logic = (project in file("logic")).dependsOn(common).settings(commonSettings:_*)
```

here is the logic module sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  spark_sql.exclude("io.netty", "netty"),
  embedded_elasticsearch % "test",
  scalatest % "test"
)

dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.6.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotation" % "2.6.5",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"
)

assemblyJarName in assembly := "***.jar"
```

Comment: Are you on sbt 0.13.x or 1.x?

Comment: I am using sbt 1.1.0

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608764/loading-the-right-dependencies-for-sbt-console-in-multi-project-setup helps you (and the linked git repository) however my problem there seems to be a bit similar.