# loading the right dependencies for sbt console in multi project setup causing derby security exception

Tags: dependencies, sbt, derby, securityexception, multi-project

I have a SBT multi project setup outlined https://github.com/geoHeil/sf-sbt-multiproject-dependency-problem and want to be able to execute `sbt console` in the root project.

When executing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
spark.sql("CREATE database foo")
```

in the root console the error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

Strangely, it works just fine in the sub project:

```
sbt
project common
console
```

and now pasting the same code.

### questions

- How can I fix sbt console to directly load the right dependencies?
- How can I load the console directly from the sub project? sbt common/console does not seem to fix the issue.

### details

The most important settings below:

```
lazy val global = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )
  .aggregate(
    common
  )
  .dependsOn(
    common
  )

lazy val common = project
  .settings(
    name := "common",
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )

lazy val dependencies =
  new {
    val sparkV    = "2.3.0"

    val sparkBase           = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"                 % sparkV % "provided"
    val sparkSql            = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"                  % sparkV % "provided"
    val sparkHive           = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive"                 % sparkV % "provided"
  }

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  dependencies.sparkBase,
  dependencies.sparkHive,
  dependencies.sparkSql
)

lazy val settings = commonSettings
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  fork := true,
  run in Compile := Defaults
    .runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass.in(Compile, run), runner.in(Compile, run))
    .evaluated
)
```

### related questions

- [Transitive dependency errors in SBT multi-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647222/transitive-dependency-errors-in-sbt-multi-project?rq=1)
- [SBT test does not work for spark test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008343/sbt-test-does-not-work-for-spark-test)

## edit

The strange thing is: for spark version 2.2.0 this setup works just fine. Only 2.2.1 / 2.3.0 cause these problems, but work fine in a single project setup or when the console is started in the right project.

Also

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission( "engine", "usederbyinternals" )'
```

is mentioned in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [SBT test does not work for spark test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008343/sbt-test-does-not-work-for-spark-test)
using the code of:

```
 if (appName === "dev") {
      System.setSecurityManager(null)
  }
```

is fixing it for development.

https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/148
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22918